# Extract data inside a tag

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I read some posts about this theme, and i try to implement the answers, but i dont have the output that i want.

This is the code HTML

```
<div class="span-8">
  <dl>
    <dt>
      <a title="A Coruña" href="http://www.paginasamarillas.es/all_a-coru%C3%B1a_.html"> A Coruña</a>
    </dt>
    <dt>
      <a title="Álava" href="http://www.paginasamarillas.es/all_alava_.html"> Álava</a>
    </dt>
    <dt>
      <a title="Albacete" href="http://www.paginasamarillas.es/all_albacete_.html"> Albacete</a>
    </dt>
    <dt>
      <a title="Alicante" href="http://www.paginasamarillas.es/all_alicante_.html"> Alicante</a>
      </dt>
...
...
```

And i want to get "Barcelona", "Alicante","Albacete", etc.
So, I try the follow code:

```
var nodos = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='container']");
```

and

```
var nodos = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@title]");
```

or

```
var nodos = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='span-8']");
```

But doesn't work, it's like if the class "container", the attribute "title" or class "span-8" don't exist in the page.
Also try others variants.
Exist others "div" with the class 'container', and others "a" with attribute 'title' in the code, that extract fine, but it's not what I want.

EDIT

Sory, I explain wrong.
Is not a single word, is a group of data.
I modify the HTML code of above.

Comment: If you just want to take Barcelona from anchor tag,  you can use simply ``document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].text``

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your sample html and it works:

```
string html = @"<div class=""container"">
  <div class=""span-24"">
    <div class=""span-8"">
      <dl>
        <dt>
          <a title=""A Coruña"" href=""http://www.example.com/all_example.html""> Barcelona</a>
        </dt>
      </dl>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>";

var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
var div = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='span-8']");
if(div != null)
{
    List<string> linkTexts = div.Descendants("a")
            .Select(a => a.InnerText)
            .ToList();  // one item " Barcelona"
}
```